# Is it possible for a lambda to access the scope of the function where it's being called?

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

This might not be the best title, but what I was wondering was something like:

```
def foo(df, column, func):
    return df[column].map(func)

foo(df, 'my_column', lambda d: int(d))      # for example
```

Is there anyway for `func` to access the `column` variable in the scope of `foo`?

(Yes, I know there are workarounds for this, I just want to know if that is possible in any way)

Comment: why do you ask about lambdas? They are equivalent to normal functions. In any case, it isn't really clear to me what you are asking. It sounds like you are asking for dynamic scoping (again, not sure), but Python uses lexical scoping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, `functools.partial` is what you want:

```
from functools import partial

def func(col, x): return x if col==0 else x*2;

def foo(df, column, func):
    return df[column].map(partial(func, column))

# toy df
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(8).reshape(4,2))

print(foo(df,1,func))
#0     2
#1     6
#2    10
#3    14
#Name: 1, dtype: int64

print(foo(df,0,func))
# equivalently:
# foo(df, 0, lambda col, x: x if col==0 else x*2)

#0    0
#1    2
#2    4
#3    6
#Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

Comment: That's a bit different than what I was thinking but it actually solves my problem better than I'd thought! Thanks :D